# Show Total Retrieved Documents

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, tf-idf, inverted-index

I am using TF-IDF algorithm to retrieve the relevant documents with the query that i input. I have successfully retrieve the relevant documents, and show it too. But i want to show the TOTAL documents that has been retrieved.

I am using this code (in result.html)to count the documents, but it show anything.

```
{% for i in result %}
  {{i.pekerjaan.count}}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the main.py :

```
result = []
    for i in range(len(list_of_query)):
        l = []
        for j in range(len(tokens_doc)):
            dic = {}
            for kata in list_of_query[i]:
                sums = 0
                ind = queries.index(kata)
                #print(ind)
                for val in weight[ind][j].values():
                    sums += val
            if(sums!= 0):
                dic['docno'] = j+1
                dic['score'] = sums
                dic['deskripsi'] = doc_deskripsi[j]
                dic['pekerjaan'] = doc_pekerjaan[j]
    #             dic['text'] = doc_text[j]
            if(len(dic) != 0): l.append(dic)
        result.append(l)

    result

    a=0

    for i in range(len(list_of_query)):
        result[i] = sorted(result[i], key = lambda x : x['score'], reverse = True)

    for i in range(len(list_of_query)):
        with open('resultquery.txt'.format(counter = i+1), 'w') as f:
            f.write('Top 5 Documents :\n')
            f.write('q_Id - DOC NO - Pekerjaan - SCORE\n')
            if len(result[i]) > 5:
                for x in range(5):
                    c = i + 1
                    f.write('%s   -   %s   -   %s   -   %s\n' %(c,doc_number[result[i][x]['docno']-1],result[i][x]['title'],result[i][x]['score']))
            else:
                for x in result[i]:
                    c  = i + 1
                    f.write('%s   -   %s   -   %s   -   %s\n' %(c,doc_number[x['docno']-1],x['pekerjaan'],x['score']))
```

The result is like this picture below, that show NULL (after Result :)

[image: result]

Like this picture above, it just show the documents, but not the total document.

The output that I expected should be like this:

[image]

I hope some one can help me fix this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Post your models / queryset

Comment: i am so sorry, but i don't get it. Can you explain more clearly, please. Thank you.

Comment: Provide code that generate `result` and corresponding models from `models.py`. In particular, how `pekerjaan` field is declared.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, and i have post it with name ```main.py```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to refer to [`count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#count) that is supposed to be used with `Manager` (as if you got results from database using django ORM), but actually you are providing a dict instead.

You can use either [`length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#length) filter like this:

```
{% for i in result %}
  {{ i.pekerjaan|length }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or prepopulate length of results into dict, like this:

main.py:

```
# ...
if(sums!= 0):
    dic['docno'] = j+1
    dic['score'] = sums
    dic['deskripsi'] = doc_deskripsi[j]
    dic['pekerjaan'] = doc_pekerjaan[j]
    dic['len_pekerjaan'] = len(doc_pekerjaan[j])
if(len(dic) != 0): l.append(dic)
```

and output it in template:

```
{% for i in result %}
  {{ i.len_pekerjaan }}
{% endfor %}
```